# Insert...on duplicate key update- repeatedly inserting

Tags: php, mysql

In my Document table I have:
`id (auto int index),
user_id (P.key and links to other table),
Doc_Name,
abstract`

When I use the code below, it just inserts another row so I have two user_id's the same when it should have updated. Obviously the id just carries on in number as it is auto int and I'm not sure if this has something do with why it won't work.

```
 $the_query = sprintf("INSERT INTO `document` (`user_id`,`Doc_Name`,`abstract`)
 VALUES ('%d','%s','%s')",'$user_id', '$Doc_Name', '$abstract')
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
 user_id=user_id+'$user_id',
 Doc_Name=Doc_Name+'$Doc_Name',
 abstract=abstract+'$abstract' "
 );
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE Document`

Answer (score 0):

Cargo cult programming? Using sprintf() without any `%` placeholders is just.... WRONG. As well, why the addition on the updated fields?

MySQL uses `concat()` for concatenation. `+` is purely a mathematical operation. Doing `'a' + 'a'` does NOT give you `aa`, you'll get `0`.

Comment: I did have the % placeholders but it wasnt working but can put the back in. edited

Answer (score 0):

if `user_id` is unique field in your table, your query should look like this:

```
$query = sprintf("
INSERT INTO
    `document`(`user_id`, `Doc_Name`, `abstract`)
VALUES
    ('%s', '%s', '%s')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `Doc_Name` = VALUES(`Doc_Name`),
    `abstract` = VALUES(`abstract`)
", $user_id, $Doc_Name, $abstract);
```

Comment: If i have the session running will i need to add something like `WHERE id='$_SESSION[user_id]'` as nothing happened with the code above

Comment: ok, then you should add unique field: `ALTER TABLE document ADD UNIQUE(user_id)`